# How to display value from array in Checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following array in model project:

```
PAYMENT_TYPE = ['in bar', 'bargeldlose Zahlung', 'E-Geld']
```

I have view new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @project, url: {action: 'create'} do |f| %>
<p>
  <%= f.label 'Titel' %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
</p>
<P>
  <%= f.label 'Budget' %>
  <%= f.text_field :price %>
  
  für
  
  <%= f.select :price_category, Project::PRICE_CATEGORIES %>
</P>
<p>
  <%= f.label 'Beschreibung' %>
  <%= f.text_area :description %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label 'Kategorie' %>
  <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= f.label 'Professionelle Freelancer Kenntnisse' %>
  <%= f.text_field :skill %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= f.label 'Ort' %>
  <%= f.text_field :location %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= f.label 'Möglichkeit der Zahlung' %>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :payment, Project::PAYMENT_TYPE do |t| %> 
    <%= t.check_box %>
    <%= t.label %>
  <% end %>
</p>

<P>
  <%= f.submit 'erstellen' %>    
</P>

<% end %>
```

I use `<%= f.collection_check_boxes :payment, Project::PAYMENT_TYPE do |t| %>`

But this code does not work. Which attribute do I need add in this helper method?

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes ⇒ the collection itself goes as a third argument. I guess it should be `<%= f.collection_check_boxes :project, :payment, Project::PAYMENT_TYPE do |t| %>`.

Comment: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 4..6)

Comment: Well, have you taken a look at the docs I linked? `<%= f.collection_check_boxes :project, :payment, Project::PAYMENT_TYPE, :itself do |t| %>` then. (Or `:to_s` instead of `:itself` if you are using not the modern ruby version.)

Comment: with this code display error: undefined method `map' for :payment:Symbol
Did you mean?  tap

Comment: @mudasobwa: the form shown in the OP is correct when the call is nested inside a form_for in this way.  The object is inferred from the form_for block.

I suspect that problem with the collection_check_boxes call is that it does not have enough information to know what value to use for 'value' and 'label'.  The API allows you to specify a method to call on the items in the collection.  If you're using ruby 2.2.x you might use :itself; otherwise :to_s would work since you're dealing with strings.

f.collection_check_boxes :payment, Project::PAYMENT_TYPE, :itself, :itself

Comment: big, big, big thank you!!!

Comment: All that model referencing in the view makes my eyes hurt. You've got very tight coupling between the view and your models. Why not have your controller (or better yet, a PORO service object) generate a hash for use by your views? The format/content of the hash is essentially a contract between the view and whatever object is creating the hash. That way, you can make changes to your controller, service object, or models and (as long as the contract is honored) have no problems in your view. FWIW.

Comment: Thanks, jvillian. Can you more explain, wht you mean have controller, what will generate metodhs in this controller? Mayebe can you show me more examples?